# TypeError: variable.getHours(); is undefined, where variable = Date.now()?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Am looking to get the current Datetime, and extract Hours, Minutes, etc., for adding a timestamp to messages..

Why does the console log `TypeError: Date.datetimeNow is undefined` for this:

```
var datetimeNow = Date.now();
var hourNow = datetimeNow.getHours();
var minuteNow = datetimeNow.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Your error message does not match your code. You'd be getting something like `'datetimeNow.getHours' is not a function`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var datetimeNow = Date.now();
```

try this:

```
var datetimeNow = new Date();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var datetimeNow = new Date();
var hourNow = datetimeNow.getHours();
var minuteNow = datetimeNow.getMinutes();
```

You need to init `datetimeNow` as date object

Answer (score 4):

`Date.now()` returns a number representing the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (1970/1/1 00:00:00.000 UTC). Numbers don't have Date methods.

To use Date methods, you need to initialize `datetimeNow` as a `Date` object.

```
var datetimeNow = new Date();
```